# passing a boolean through axios to express route, but no longer acting like a boolean

Tags: node.js, express, axios, switch-statement, boolean

The desired outcome is that this switch statement will choose a route based on whether the toggle is "true" or "false". However, right now it goes to the default route no matter what the value is.

```
    router.post('/team_activate/:team_oid/:toggle', function(req, res) {
        
        console.log("req.params.toggle: "+req.params.toggle)

        switch (req.params.toggle){
            case true:
                console.log("Live")
                Team.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.team_oid}, {"$set": { "active": req.params.toggle, "status": "Live" }}).exec(function(err, doc){
                    if(err){
                        throw(err);
                    } else {
                        res.send(doc)
                    }
                })
            break;

            default:
                console.log("Paused")
                Team.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.team_oid}, {"$set": { "active": req.params.toggle, "status": "Paused" }}).exec(function(err, doc){
                    if(err){
                        throw(err);
                    } else {
                        res.send(doc)
                    }
                })
            break;
        }
   })
```

The console.logs read out like this:

```
req.params.toggle: true
Paused
req.params.toggle: false
Paused
req.params.toggle: true
Paused
req.params.toggle: false
Paused
req.params.toggle: true
Paused
req.params.toggle: false
Paused
req.params.toggle: true
Paused
req.params.toggle: false
Paused
req.params.toggle: true
Paused
```

Before this I did a simple "if(req.params.toggle)" statement, but it didn't work either. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to parse it to boolean because express send string to the router/controller not bool.

you can use `toggle === 'true' ? true : false`
to parse it

Comment: I tried that, like this: 
 let boolean = Boolean(req.params.toggle)

 switch (boolean)

It didn't work.

Comment: Ah, I tried the second approach and it worked!! Whew. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Thanks for the comment  I will fix my response. @IsraelPeck

Answer (score 1):

Any request response is stringified in the transition, so sending and consuming applications need to serialize and deserialize JSON objects respectively,

In your case, you are directly expecting it to be boolean, but it is a string, you will need to parse before using it.

You can go with either of

```
let toggle = new Boolean(req.params.toggle);
```

or

```
let toggle = req.params.toggle === 'true' ? true : false;
```

and use `toggle` in the switch condition, the first one is the better approach